# Uniform Integrability and Conditional Expectations

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, martingales

Let $X=\{X_n:n\in \mathbb{N_0}\}$ be a supermartingale or a submartingale on a filtered space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\{\mathcal{F}_{n}\},\mathbf{P}).$ Suppose the sequence $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}$ is uniformly integrable $\left( \text{i.e.} \lim \limits_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty} \sup _{n \in \mathbb{N}_0} E\left(\left|X_{n}\right| \mathbf{1}_{\left\{\left|X_{n}\right|>\lambda\right\}}\right)=0\right)$,then  we have $\sup _{n \in \mathbb{N}_0} E\left(\left|X_{n}\right|\right)<\infty$.By *Doob's Martingale Convergence Theorem* (discrete case),there exits a random variable $X_{\infty}$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbf{P})$,such that $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_{n}=X_{\infty}\text{ a.s.}$.Since uniformly integrability of $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}$,then $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left\|X_{n}-X_{\infty}\right\|_{1}=0$, that is, the sequence $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}$ converges to $X_{\infty}$ in the $L^{1}$ norm.

For any fixed $k\in\mathbb{N_0},$can we have $$
\boxed{\mathbf{E}(X_\infty\big|\mathcal{F_{k}})=\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbf{E}(X_n\big|\mathcal{F_{k}})\text{ a.s.}\quad?}
$$

I doubt the validity of this equation.Surely,$X_n \to X_{\infty}$ in $L^1$ implies $\mathbf{E}(X_n\big|\mathcal{F_{k}})\to\mathbf{E}(X_{\infty}|\mathcal{F_{k}})$ in $L^1$.But from this we only know that there exists a subsequence $\left\{\mathbf{E}(X_{n_{\ell}}\big|\mathcal{F_{k}}): \ell \in \mathbb{N}_{0}\right\}$ such that $$\mathbf{E}(X_\infty\big|\mathcal{F_{k}})=\lim \limits_{\ell \rightarrow \infty}\mathbf{E}(X_{n_{\ell}}\big|\mathcal{F_{k}})\text{ a.s.}\quad$$

I feel the condition $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_{n}=X_{\infty}\text{ a.s.}$ doesn't contribute to deducing $$\mathbf{E}(X_\infty\big|\mathcal{F_{k}})=\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbf{E}(X_n\big|\mathcal{F_{k}})\text{ a.s.}$$

How to construct a counterexample to show its invalidity, or prove its correctness ?

Answer (score 5):

The sequence $\left(\mathbb E\left[X_n\mid\mathcal F_k\right]\right)_{n\geqslant k}$ is monotonic (non-increasing in the case of a supermartingale, non-decreasing in the case of a submartingale). Moreover, $\left(\mathbb E\left[X_n\mid\mathcal F_k\right]\right)_{n\geqslant k}$ converges in probability to $\mathbb E\left[X_\infty\mid\mathcal F_k\right]$  hence the convergence takes place in the almost sure sense.

Comment: Opps ! I completely forgot about the condition of monotonicity. THX !

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It is easy to check that  $(E(X_n|\mathcal F_k))$ is a sub/super-martingale.

$P(E(X_n|\mathcal F_k)|>\Delta)\le \frac 1 {\Delta} E|X_n|$. Use this  to show that $(E(X_n|\mathcal F_k)) $ is uniformly integrable (which gives a.s. convergence). [Recall that  family $(X_i)$ is uniformly integrable if and only if

1. $\sup E|X_i| <\infty$ and
2. For any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\int_{A} |X_i|dP<\epsilon$ for all $i$ whenever $P(A) <\delta$].

Comment: Based on my understanding,$$(1).\sup _{n \in \mathbb{N}_0} E\left(\left|X_{n}\right|\right)<\infty + (2).\mathbf{P}(|\mathbf{E}(X_n\Big|\mathcal F_k)|>\Delta)\le \frac 1 {\Delta} \mathbf{E}|X_n|(\text{the Markov's inequality})\Rightarrow$$   the $\left\{E(X_n|\mathcal F_k)\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0} $ is uniformly integrable. And then,using *Doob's Martingale Convergence Theorem (discrete case)* again, it a.s.convergence.  Those as you said.

Comment: Until now,we only know that $\left\{\mathbf{E}(X_n|\mathcal F_k)\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0} $ converges almost surely to some random variable  $Y,$so next step we need further explain $\mathbf{E}(X_\infty\big|\mathcal{F_{k}})=Y\text{ a.s.}$ But to explaining that,we will back to  the method given by @Davide Giraudo.

Comment: You already said you have $L^{1}$ convergence to the right limit. You cannot have different r.v.'s $Y$ and $Z$ such that $X_n \to Y$ in $L^{1}$ and $X_n \to Z$ a.s. @user250236

Comment: Oh,both $L^1$ and $\text{a.s.}$ convergence imply convergence in probability.So the limits, if they exist, must to be the same. THX!

Comment: Yes, that is right. My answer is not the shortest, but I think it contains additional information about $(E(X_n|\mathcal F_k))$. @user250236

Comment: Just a side note: $(\mathbf E(X_n\mid\mathcal F_k))$ is uniformly integrable because it converges in $L^1$ (as OP said: “$X_n\to X_\infty$ in $L^1$ implies $\mathbf E(X_n\mid\mathcal{F_{k}})\to\mathbf{E}(X_{\infty}\mid\mathcal{F_{k}})$ in $L^1$”).

Comment: @geetha290krm I might have missed something, but how do you check that $(\mathbf E(X_n\mid\mathcal F_k))$ is a martingale? (It surely is as a process in $k$, but I don't see it as a process in $n$.)

Comment: $k$ is fixed. It is a martingale in $n$.  @nejimban

Comment: Restrict to $n \geq k$. @nejimban

Comment: @geetha290krm So I suppose you assumed that $(X_n)$ were itself a martingale to start with? Otherwise, consider the submartingale (bounded in $L^2$) $X_n:=B_1+\cdots+B_n$ with independent $B_k\sim\text{Bernoulli}(k^{-2})$ and the natural filtration. Then $Y_n:=\mathbf E[X_n\mid\mathcal F_1]=B_1+\sum_{k=2}^nk^{-2}$ (for $n\ge1$) cannot be a martingale because $Y_{n+1}-Y_n={(n+1)}^{-2}$.

Comment: @nejimban I meant to say it is a sub/super-martingale according as $(X_n)$ is a  sub/super-martingale.